# Do you associate the "Cause of Death" fact with the death GRO entry?

Tags: ancestry.com, cause-of-death, citation

I always associate the death GRO reference with the "Death". If I go so far as you acquire a death certificate I then find out the "Cause of Death". So I add it as a fact.

But it occurred to me that I don't link this fact to any official citation. Is it standard to simply associate it with the same GRO citation? Since that is ultimately how to find the info out?

Comment: I've added the Ancestry tag that you left out...

Answer (score 3):

Cause of Death should **not** be a new Fact, but rather a Cause field for the existing Death Fact.

As such, it would share the sources cited for the Death fact (which in this case would be the Death certificate and the GRO index details), although only the Death certificate would provide the cause info (as well as exact place, age, address, informant, etc...)

In places such as Ancestry (which doesn't do Gedcom compliance very well), you can add the Cause of Death in the Death fact description; or it you decide to use the non-standard Cause of Death fact they provide, you would only cite the Certificate and not the GRO index reference (as that doesn't tell you anything about cause of death).

Comment: Alright. But in Ancestry that is how it is designed. You add a Cause of Death entry from the list.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Ancestry is pretty poor at Gedcom compliance.

Comment: At the very least you have confirmed I should link it to the source for the death. So thanks for that.